# Showing like number format of two numbers separated by dashes in Excel

Tags: excel

[image: my excel data]

I have data written like added picture that is text format, for this reason i can't draw a graph. By the way, i update this excel table day by day via copy-paste from any website as this format. How can change text format to number format in this table?

[image]

Comment: You want to perform the subtraction? What is the result you want to get?

Comment: What sort of graph are you expecting?  Can you mock something up by drawing it manually (e.g. in Paint) to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two formula to extract the left and right parts of the string.

### If the string is *always* like `###-###` then

Low Range Formula

```
=--LEFT(A2,3)
```

High Range Formula

```
=--MID(A2,5,3)
```

### If the string is  like `One or More Digits-One or More Digits` then

Low Range Formula

```
=--LEFT(A4,FIND("-",A4)-1)
```

High Range Formula

```
=--MID(A4,FIND("-",A4)+1,999)
```

---

Note: the `=--` prefix converts the extracted string to a number (assuming it's numeric)

Comment: What if range be like "95-100"?
=--LEFT(A4,FIND("-",A4)-1) formula gives
95 and 0

Comment: I just added "**" for indicate. Additionaly, secondly written Low Range Formula and High Range Formula is same. A4 values 95-100.

Comment: Argh! that was a typo.  Fixed now